# Saving persistent text file in internal storage

Tags: android

This question his perhaps more a request for some advice how to save some data in the best way. I'm doing an app where I tag images from the device with contacts from the ContactsContract in the device   by saving the filepath for the image together with the selected contact, and by contact, I guess it's enough to save the ID or the name of that contact?

I need some advice how I should use the FileOutputStream to write this data. Should I, and can I save the strings like "filepath, id" for each row in the file or what's the best way? I also need to search if the filepath and contact is already in the file aswell as be able to tag several contacts to an image. First I thought I could use a file for each image and add all the contacts that are tagged with it, but that is perhaps not a good way to do it?!

Preciate some advice!

EDIT:

If I use Shared Preferences then I could use the contacts ID as a key and the image path as the value? Then I can add several unique ID keys with different values? But I guess, I can't add more than one value to a key?

Comment: You may try to use sqlite for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of structured data system.

Have you tried SQLite? - SQLite seems good for the job.

```
CREATE TABLE `contact`('id' INT , 'contact_id' TEXT, 'image_file_path' TEXT, TEXT, PRIMARY KEY('id'))
```

You search feature is easy then;

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact_id ='1'
```

I would start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: Yes that would be nice, but this is a task that must use files! The use of SQLite is the next step in this task and I guess much easier! Men tack för tipset! :)

Comment: If you must use files, you need to investigate a file format for structure data, Maybe try JSON ;p

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You can insert the contact details by converting it to jsonstring and put in a sharedPreferences.

Example:

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Contactid", 1);
    obj.put("ImagePath", "/sdcard/download/a.png");

String jsonstring=obj.toString();
```

if you have multiple contacts than use json Array Like this

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray("ContactDetails");
for(int i=0;i<noofcontacts;i++)
{
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Contactid", 1);
        obj.put("ImagePath", "/sdcard/download/a.png");
        array.put(obj);
}
jsonstring= array.toString();
```

save contact details in the SharedPreferences like this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("contactDetails", jsonstring);
    editor.commit();
```

Now get SharedPreference values

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String jsoncontactdetails= sharedPreferences.getString("contactDetails", null);
```

I hope you know Json Parsing.

---

Using Database is the best option in this case. Because it is hard to maintain each file in the internal storage and it also consume some processing time. Best is the contact the image path of the contact in the database .

Comment: @3D-kreativ In what way you need my help..?

Comment: Would it be better with Using Shared Preferences?